# Try to generate a dynamic field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, field

I want to generate a dinamic field in my form on Rails. This is the code:

```
<%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>
  <% if @item.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@item.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this item     from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @item.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
  <% end %>

 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :vehicle %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :vehicle %>
  </div>
 <div class="field">
<%= f.label :part %><br>
<%= f.text_field :part %>
  </div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
   <% end %>
```

My idea is put a script into the form where i can generate a field part dinamicaly with a button with a text like "add" for another part field. Any idea?? Thanks everyone.

Comment: You have not, as far as I can tell, provided enough information to answer this question. Maybe provide an example of the output from the page that you want to accomplish so we know what you are trying to do? Also, the english word you want is "dynamically" - you might get better responses if you correct that spelling on the title.

Comment: I'll try back ...Sorry